# Volume $2$ of Geometric Nonlinear Functional Analysis?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request

Benyamini and Lindenstrauss published a book entitled 'Geometric Nonlinear Functional Analysis, Volume 1' in American Mathematical Society, Colloquium Publication.

Since it is volume $1$, I believe it should have volume $2$, which is mentioned in the introduction of volume $1$. The authors even give an outline of what will be covered in volume $2$.

However, I couldn't find volume 2 in AMS bookstore. I even googled the book online and it is nowhere to be found.

Question: Does the author published volume $2$?

Comment: Probably the easiest thing to do is contact the author. Lindenstrauss died in 2012, but you might try writing to Benyamini.

Comment: There have been many "volume 1"s for which a volume 2 has never appeared.

Comment: I emailed Professor Benyamini. He replied that volume 2 is not written.